# Swipe Gesture between UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have an ViewController class, where i have an UIView called `templateView` on self.view, which consists of an UIView called `gridView`, here i need to swipe on `templateView`, for that i have added swipegesture like,

```
swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction)];
swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction)];

swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRight.delegate = self;

swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.delegate = self;

 [templateView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
 [templateView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

In the `swipeRight` and `swipeLeft` i need to move the `gridView` left side and right side.. What i need to implement in these  methods..?

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest

1. Use a gesture handler that takes a parameter (in case you ever add gestures to multiple views);
2. Make sure the view in question has `userInteractionEnabled` turned on.
3. You don't need to set the gesture's `delegate` unless you're implementing one of the [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods.

Thus, the configuration might look like:

```
templateView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[templateView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[templateView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

And then the gesture handler might look like:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGRect frame = self.gridView.frame;

    // I don't know how far you want to move the grid view.
    // This moves it off screen.
    // Adjust this to move it the appropriate amount for your desired UI

    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
        frame.origin.x += self.view.bounds.size.width;
    else if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
        frame.origin.x -= self.view.bounds.size.width;
    else
        NSLog(@"Unrecognized swipe direction");

    // Now animate the changing of the frame

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.gridView.frame = frame;
                     }];
}
```

Note, if you're using auto layout and if the view is defined by constraints rather than `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, then this handler code would have to change appropriately. But hopefully this gives you the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the gridView by using some UIViewAnimations. 
Create something like that:

```
-(void)swipeRightAction{
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    gridView.frame = CGRectMake(320,0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code will change the frame of your gridView. You need to change this parameter according to where you want to slide your view.
I didn't try the code, let me know if it works.