# UISwipeGestureRecognizer left direction not recognized

Tags: swipe, direction, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I´m using a **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** on an **UIButton** which is
connected to an **IBAction** handleSwipe:

```
- (IBAction) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) swipeRecognizer {
 NSLog(@"handleSwipe: %i",[swipeRecognizer direction]);
}
```

Unfortunately only right swipes are recognized. I don´t see any settings to limit the swipes to left or right. Any ideas?

Comment: [This][1] answer will help you more.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498127/1223897

Comment: Can you paste some code how you are implementing so others can help you more and also makes it easy to understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you mentioned is the [`direction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer/1619178-direction?language=objc) property, introduced on iOS 3.2. To recognise left and right swipe just do

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

where `swipeGestureRecognizer` is your instance of `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.